# Getting error installing the ruby racer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle, therubyracer

I am trying to install ruby but everytime `sudo bundle --without production` the installation crash when it comes to therubyracer:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for main() in -lobjc... yes
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

    Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/therubyracer-0.9.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/therubyracer-0.9.10/ext/v8/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.9.10), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.9.10'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Is there any way to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Try this $ gem uninstall libv8  and

$ gem install therubyracer

Comment: already tried but even if therubyracer installs successfully I get the error message when running 'bundle'